# Jquery causing 'Error Loading Page'

Tags: javascript, jquery

'jquery-1.11.3.min.js' seems to be causing the links in my navigation bar not to work.
Whenever I try to click the message icon, a line of text appears down the very bottom saying 'Error loading page'. I don't know how to fix the issue.

These are the scripts I have which are required to run

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
```

And this is my code, apologies for it being poorly written I'm a beginner.

```
<body>

<!--HEADER-->
<div id="header">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <div id="left"><li><a href="#menu" ><img src="images/user.svg" width="30px" alt="user"></a></li></div>
            <li id="centre" class="logo">EROS</li>
            <div id="right"><li><a href="message.html"><img src="images/message.svg" width="50px" alt="messages"></a></li></div>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<!--END HEADER-->

<!--MAIN-->
<div id="main">

    <div id="container">
        <div class="buddy" style="display: block;">
                <div class="avatar"  style="margin: 0 auto; display: block; background-image:url(images/girl1.jpg)"></div>
                    <div class="bio">
                    <h1>Name, 28</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buddy">
            <div class="avatar" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block; background-image:url(images/flower1.png)"></div>
                <div class="bio">
            <h1>Steve, 28</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>

        </div>  

        <div class="buddy">
            <div class="avatar" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block; background-image:url(images/flower2.png)"></div>
                <div class="bio">
            <h1>Name, 28</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>

        </div>  
        <div class="buddy">
                <div class="avatar" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block; background-image:url(images/flower3.png)"></div>
                    <div class="bio">
                <h1>Name, 28</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>

        </div>  
   </div>


        <!--<div id="process">
            <canvas id="pjs"></canvas>
        </div>-->

            <div id="controls">
                <img src="images/bye.svg" alt="no" width="150px" class="bye">
                <img src="images/star.svg" alt="star" width="50px" class="star">
                <img src="images/hi.svg" alt="yes" width="150px" class="hi">
            </div>
</div>
<!--END MAIN-->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".buddy").on("swiperight",function(){
  $(this).addClass('rotate-left').delay(700).fadeOut(1);
  $('.buddy').find('.status').remove();
  $(this).append('<div class="status like">Like!</div>');   

  if ( $(this).is(':last-child') ) {
    $('.buddy:nth-child(1)').removeClass ('rotate-left rotate-right').fadeIn(300);
   } else {
      $(this).next().removeClass('rotate-left rotate-right').fadeIn(400);
   }
  });  

 $(".buddy").on("swipeleft",function(){
  $(this).addClass('rotate-right').delay(700).fadeOut(1);
  $('.buddy').find('.status').remove();
  $(this).append('<div class="status dislike">Dislike!</div>');

  if ( $(this).is(':last-child') ) {
   $('.buddy:nth-child(1)').removeClass ('rotate-left rotate-right').fadeIn(300);
 } else {
    $(this).next().removeClass('rotate-left rotate-right').fadeIn(400);
 } 
 });

 $(".bye").on("click", function(){
 $(".buddy").not(".rotate-left, .rotate-right").trigger("swipeleft");
 });
 $(".hi").on("click", function(){
 $(".buddy").not(".rotate-left, .rotate-right").trigger("swiperight");
 });
 });

</script>
</body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what appears in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/eros/message.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
send    @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
m.extend.ajax   @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
(anonymous function)    @   jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js:3
a.widget._loadUrl   @   jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js:4
(anonymous function)    @   jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js:3
a.widget.change @   jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js:4
(anonymous function)    @   jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js:3
(anonymous function)    @   jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js:3
m.extend.each   @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
m.fn.m.each @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
a.fn.(anonymous function)   @   jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js:3
a.mobile.changePage @   jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js:4
(anonymous function)    @   jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js:4
m.event.dispatch    @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
r.handle    @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
```

Comment: can you post the error which you are seeing in console?

Comment: Error is self explantory: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/eros/message.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.` Add URL not file.

Comment: The error is probably here <a href="message.html">...</a>. Unless you run the code on server browsers will not able to serve the file. This is for security reason and it is commonly termed as CORS. IN stackoverflow you may find numerous thread addressing this cors. Try one by removing the message.html